# What is the way to make file version reflect both product build number and version of the specific dll/exe?

Tags: git, visual-studio, teamcity, build-process, versioning

What is the way to make file version reflect both product build number and version
of the specific dll (version considered changed when  version control system revision number is changed
for the source project for the file) on the build server. How to to achieve this  with minimal efforts?

My build env. : Git, TeamCity, Visual Studio, Nant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the way to make file version reflect both product build number and version of the specific dll

You have 2 simple and fast options:

1. `git tag`
2. `git notes`

---

### ***`git tag`***

Create an annotated tag.
Annotated tags are created using the `-a` flag.

The difference between regular tag to annotated tag is that the annotated tag is like a commit, it contain the date, author and the message attached to it.

Once you create the tags simply push it to the github repository 
`git push --tags`.

```
# Creating annotated tag
git tag -a
```

---

### ***`git notes`***

Add a notes to the commit. The notes are not part of the commit message and can be modified if needed later on with no effect on the commit SHA-1

```
# Add a note to any desired commit
git notes add -m 'Dll version #xxx, Build#yyy' 72a144e2
```